# C# LINQ append multiple items rather than returning its array

Tags: c#, linq

Consider this situation:

```
struct Account
{
    public List<string> CharacterNames;
}
List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
// add items to accounts here

accounts.Select(a=>a.CharacterNames); // I want it to select string, not string[].
```

So it gives me character name lists. But what I want is all character names.

Is there a LINQ solution to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `SelectMany` to flatten the results:

```
accounts.SelectMany(a => a.CharacterNames);
```

Comment: feel clear! however it's very hard to search through google this kind of question.